# Python generating a lookup table of lambda expressions

Tags: python, function, lambda, functional-programming, anonymous-function

I'm building a game and in order to make it work, I need to generate a list of "pre-built" or "ready to call" expressions.  I'm trying to do this with lambda expressions, but am running into an issue generating the lookup table.  The code I have is similar to the following:

```
import inspect

def test(*args):
    string = "Test Function: "
    for i in args:
        string += str(i) + " "
    print(string)

funct_list = []

# The problem is in this for loop
for i in range(20):
    funct_list.append(lambda: test(i, "Hello World"))

for i in funct_list:
    print(inspect.getsource(i))
```

The output I get is:

```
funct_list.append(lambda: test(i, "Hello World"))
funct_list.append(lambda: test(i, "Hello World"))
funct_list.append(lambda: test(i, "Hello World"))
funct_list.append(lambda: test(i, "Hello World"))
...
```

and I need it to go:

```
funct_list.append(lambda: test(1, "Hello World"))
funct_list.append(lambda: test(2, "Hello World"))
funct_list.append(lambda: test(3, "Hello World"))
funct_list.append(lambda: test(4, "Hello World"))
...
```

I tried both of the following and neither work

```
for i in range(20):
    funct_list.append(lambda: test(i, "Hello World"))

for i in range(20):
    x = (i, "Hello World")
    funct_list.append(lambda: test(*x))
```

My question is how do you generate lists of lambda expressions with some of the variables inside the lambda expression already set.

Comment: *Python's closures are late binding*. http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, Python's closures are *late binding*, which means that variables from an outside scope referenced in a closure (in other words, the variables *closed over*) are looked up at the moment the closure is called and *not* at the time of definition.

In your example, the closure in question is formed when your lambda references the variable `i` from the outside scope. However, when your lambda is called later on, the loop has already finished and left the variable `i` with the value 19.

An easy but not particularly elegant fix is to use a default argument for the lambda:

```
for i in range(20):
    funct_list.append(lambda x=i: test(x, "Hello World"))
```

Unlike closure variables, default arguments are bound early and therefore achieve the desired effect of capturing the value of the variable `i` at the time of lambda definition.

A better way is use `functools.partial` which allows you to partially apply some arguments of the function, "fixing" them to a certain value:

```
from functools import partial

for i in range(20):
    funct_list.append(partial(lambda x: test(x, "Hello World"), i))
```

Comment: or better yet just use `functools.partial` (which is not late binding) , and I would argue is less gross ...

Comment: Eh, but at least state why they should *use default arguments*

Comment: I was going to but I pressed submit too early by accident. I'm going to expand my answer.